# Amcharts 4 Maps center title above map

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I have a map made with amcharts 4 and I was wondering if there is any way to center the title(s) above the map.

It seems that the map fills up all the available height of the container and the text displays at the same height. I tried the `chart.svgContainer.hideOverflow = false;` to no avail.

[Here is a pen](https://codepen.io/joffreyj-the-solid/pen/VwEvRod)